# How can I have one component tell another component to re-read its data?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following in my Dashboard.razor

```
<FilteredEventsGrid Start="0"
    ShowEndDate="true"
    Filter="SmartQueries.Filter.Owner | SmartQueries.Filter.IncludeDisabled"
    CanEditOwner="false"/>

<FilteredEventsGrid Start="0"
    ShowEndDate="true"
    Filter="SmartQueries.Filter.Pending | SmartQueries.Filter.Private"
    CanEditOwner="false"/>
```

There are some events that are in both of these grids. Both of these grids allow editing events in them. So, when an event in one of the grids is edited, how can it then tell the other grid to re-read its data? (Each internally reads its data, there is no `Data` parameter.)

The best I've though of is `<FilteredEventsGrid>` has a `ValueChanged` EventCallback. And both of them have a `Refresh()` method. When they parent gets the `ValueChanged` event, it calls `Refresh()` on the other component.

Comment: what do you mean by "event in one of the grids is edited" grid was edited event ?

Comment: @Cfun yes, in one of the grids I edited a row of data. And that row is in the other grid also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a service `GridsSync.cs` to manage the synchronisation if we can call it so between the components

**GridsSync.cs**

```cs
public class GridsSync
{
    public event Action OnEdit;

    public void RequestReRead()
    {
        OnEdit?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Register the service to be used with dependency injection

**Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GridsSync>();
```

Assuming this is your component, the click of the button is a simulation of the edit event `GridEdited`, you are then triggering an event `OnEdit` that the other component has subscribed to it too, .

**Grid.razor**

```cs
@inject GridsSync GridsSync
@implements IDisposable

<h1>@ReReadStatus</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GridEdited">Simulate grid edited event</button>

@code {
    string ReReadStatus;

    public void GridEdited()
    {
        GridsSync.RequestReRead();
     }

// Subscribe upon init to the event, to listen when a re read is requested by the other grid

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        GridsSync.OnEdit += ReRead;
    }

    public void ReRead()
    {
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            ReReadStatus = "Grid performed a Re-read";
            //your re read logic goes here ...

        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GridsSync.OnEdit -= ReRead;
    }
}
```

Ps:

If your re-read logic needs to be executed on the main/ui thread then it must be done within `InvokeAsync();`, otherwise you might do it outside and then call [StateHasChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to notify the ui thread to re-render.

```
 InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
```